# aframe.js How to change shape center position?(pivot)

Tags: three.js, pivot, aframe

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/copper-past-property?path=index.html%3A13%3A76

under picture's pivot position is center

[image]

i want to pivot position to bottom center like under image.

[image]

i update example. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/copper-past-property?path=viewport.js%3A127%3A39

[image]

I want to move and resize a shape relative to the bottom, just like a 3d object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the easiest way to add an offset / pivot is by using a parent-child relation:

- insert your object inside any parent entity
- set the parents position where want your object (plus the pivot position)
- move the child in the opposite direction of where the pivot should be (so `pivot * -1`)
- perform any operations on the parent entity

For example a box at `0 0.5 -3` with a pivot at `0 -0.5 0`:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <!-- The sphere is the parent entity -->
  <a-sphere position="0 0 -3" radius="0.1" color="blue"
            animation="property: rotation; to: 360 0; loop: true; dur: 5000">
    <!--- The original, but now off-centered box --->
    <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="wireframe:true; color: #aa00ff"></a-box>
  </a-sphere>
  <!--- axis --->
  <a-box position="0 0 -3" scale="5 0.05 0.05" color="red"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

---

Your case is quite specific, as you want a pivot for the `TransformControls`.
One way would be to apply a pivot where they are attached (`viewport.js`).

The entities could have a component defining a pivot point:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("editor-config", {
  schema: {
    offset: {type: "vec3", default: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}}
  },
  init: function() {
    // once the entity is loaded
    this.el.addEventListener("loaded", evt => {
      // save the offset within the THREE.Object3D
      const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
      if (!mesh.userData) mesh.userData = {}
      mesh.userData.editoroffset = this.data.offset
    })
  }
});
// <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" editor-config="offset: 0 -0.5 0"></a-box>
```

Then when the `TransformControls` are attached - you can apply the pivot:

```
/*** setSelectEntity(entity) within viewport.js ***/

this.transformControls.attach(entity);
// reset the position
this.transformControls.position.multiplyScalar(0);
// if there is an offset to apply - use it
if (entity.userData && entity.userData.editoroffset)
  this.transformControls.position.copy(entity.userData.editoroffset)
```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-69596960?path=viewport.js%3A92%3A29)

Comment: i have additional question.

Comment: i update question. thank you!!